# Androidplot - setting margins and paddings (adjusting labels)

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I'm trying to adjust labels of X and Y axes. Sadly all solutions I could find are pretty deprecated, usage info doesnt provide this, and Api lacks of description.

My chart looks like this:
[image]

As you can see contents of plot and labels interfere. Changing paddings, margins and position of labels with these functions:

```
    // (left, top, right, bottom)
    plot.setPlotMargins(50, 0, 0, 50);
    plot.setPlotPadding(50, 0, 0, 50);

    graph.getLineLabelInsets().setLeft(PixelUtils.dpToPix(-10));
    graph.getLineLabelInsets().setBottom(PixelUtils.dpToPix(-14));
```

...results in: 
[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this, to nicely adjust the labels? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

It turned out that I used wrong padding ;)

```
XYGraphWidget graph = csvPlot.getGraph();
graph.setPadding(PixelUtils.dpToPix(20), PixelUtils.dpToPix(10), PixelUtils.dpToPix(15), PixelUtils.dpToPix(35));
```

[image]